# Store specific column from 1:N relationship on parent table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Apologies for the long question, but I want to make sure my problem is clear. Say I have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE project (
    id NUMBER(38, 0),
    status_id NUMBER(38, 0), -- FK to a status table
    title VARHCAR(4000 CHAR)
);

CREATE TABLE project_status_log (
    id NUMBER(38, 0),
    project_id NUMBER(38, 0),
    status_id NUMBER(38, 0),
    user_id NUMBER(38, 0), -- FK to a user table
    created_on DATE
);
```

Projects go through a complex workflow, where each status log entry represents a step in the workflow. An example workflow: Draft -> Submitted -> Review -> Returned To Draft -> Submitted -> Review -> Approved

Now let's say a very common need is to get the `user_id` of the user who last submitted a project. I typically create a view that I can join to `project`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW project_submitter (project_id, user_id) AS
SELECT project.project_id, submitter.user_id
FROM project
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        project_id,
        FIRST_VALUE(user_id) OVER (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY date DESC) AS user_id
    FROM project_status_log
    WHERE status_id = 5 -- ID of submitted status
) submitter
```

The problem is there are many rows and lots of helper views like this, and when I need to use many of them in a single query the performance gets really bad. Some of these queries are taking several seconds to finish. I've added indexes and made sure there aren't full table scans, but the problem seems to be all the aggregation and sub queries in a single query.

I'm considering adding a `project.submitted_by` column that is set programmatically any time a project's status is updated to submitted. This would drastically simplify my queries and make life much easier. Is this a bad approach? It feels a little bit like de-normalized data, but I'm not sure it actually is.

Are there any potential problems with a `project.submitted_by` column I'm not thinking about? If so, are there any alternatives to solve the performance issues short of putting the entire thing in an elasticsearch index?

Comment: Why are you joining to an inline view; and why are you using analytics rather than aggregation here? Anyway... denormalisation isn't necessarily always wrong, but here could end up adding more and more columns; and then do you clear that submitted value if the status regresses, and if so do you still need to find the prior submitter? etc. Have you considered materialized views?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you separate your state tables from your log tables. And not query your log tables except when you need to get something like a history. What you are doing is a step in that direction.

Other approaches to the problem include

- the creation and maintenance of read models.
- if you are ok with slightly stale data, a shortcut would be to create materialized views (based off your current views) that are refresh periodically

---

In your query, you might want to remove the `DISTINCT`. You don't need it since you are doing `FIRST_VALUE` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the query.  One method is aggregation:

```
SELECT project_id,
       MAX(user_id) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date DESC) as user_id
FROM project_status_log
WHERE status_id = 5
GROUP BY project_id;
```

Or using window functions if you really want more columns:

```
SELECT . . .   -- whatever columns you want
FROM (SELECT psl.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY project_id ORDER BY date DESC) as seqnum
      FROM project_status_log psl
      WHERE status_id = 5
     ) psl
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Oracle has a smart optimizer and it should be able to use an index on `project_status_log(status_id, project_id, date)` for both of these queries.

Note:  Sometimes views can impede the optimizer.  It might be worth trying a correlated subquery as well:

```
select p.*,
       (select psl.user_id
        from project_status_log psl
        where psl.status = 5 and psl.project_id = p.project_id
        order by date desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as user_id
from projects p;
```

The goal here is that any filtering means that the subquery is run only for the rows *after* filtering.  This also wants the same index mentioned above.